# Minecraft Not enough Items cheat mode disabled

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was making a modpack with only 10 mods (WIP) and one of them happened to be Not enough items 1.6.1.9. I loaded up my modpack and loaded the world. The mods seemed to be working just fine. NEI was also working but when I switched the mode to cheat mode, it was still in recipe mode... My lockmode is set to -1 but its still stuck in recipe mode. Also, there are no tools in the upper left hand corner for cheat mode and "gamemode" is disabled.

Comment: Did you enable cheats when you created the world? And have you tried opening it to LAN and enabling cheats that way?

Comment: Are you on a server?

Comment: Im on singleplayer and yes, I've opened to LAN and enabling cheats